# How Objective-C Runtime detect framework is exist

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making a framework that use several third party framework, and those third party framework were install by developer who use my framework using cocoapods, I got some problem and I can not find any solution.

I was `try __has_include` to detect framework is exist, that just work at compiler time not work at runtime.

The problem like below:

1. How detect framework exist at runtime.
2. I need import framework if the framework exist.
3. I need to implement the third party protocol if the framework exist.

Comment: If you need the frameworks then they should be included in the app bundle.

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes, I know but what I make is a Ad Collection SDK,so I provide serveral  ad like admob、flurry......,and I don't know which ad provider will be use, that's up to developer, so I got problem like above.

Comment: Rather than knowing which frameworks exists at runtime, it's better to implement all of them via a common API which you know will always exist.